# How to use the ini files correctly while editing and adding in Java, where reading works with ini4j?

Tags: java, linux, ini4j

How to edit exactly without breaking the lines? I have a file test.ini and i just need to add a new record on it and later only modify it. But the following is crashing my existing file.

**File: test.ini:**

Existing correct version:

```
myname=C://
field=A=B
```

After modify it becomes:

```
myname=C\://
field=A\=B
newfield=blabla\n
```

Expected output was:

```
myname=C://
field=A=B
newfield=blabla
```

**Code:**

```
//import java.util.Properties;
try {
  Properties p = new Properties();
  p.load(new FileInputStream("/var/tmp/test.ini"));
  p.setProperty(key,fieldName);        
  p.store(new FileOutputStream("/var/tmp/test.ini"), null);        
  return p.getProperty(fieldName);
} catch(Exception e) {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties files don't follow the same rules as "ini" files, notably they escape different characters - in your case it's escaping colon and equals within data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

You could use [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/) to handle the files in the appropriate way, or handle the escaping yourself after saving.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ini4j
and dont forget to use Config to change writing settings;
for instance:

```java
final Ini properties = new Ini();
Config c = new Config();
c.setFileEncoding(UTF_8);
c.setLineSeparator("\n");
c.setEscape(false);// ← here to avoid redundant '\' before ':'
properties.setConfig(c);
properties.load(is);
// do sth
properties.store(Files.newBufferedWriter(propertyPath, UTF_8));
```